# How to free a generic TList<TMyRecord> with generic sub lists in TMyRecord

Tags: delphi, generics, record, generic-list

In Delphi 10 Berlin under Windows I have the following question regarding the freeing of generic lists:

I have the following record/list structure:

```
type
  TMyRecord=record
    Value1: Real;
    SubList1: TList<Integer>;
    SubList2: TList<Real>;
  end;

  TMyListOfRecords=TList<TMyRecord>;
```

I want to free the structure with the following code:

```
var
  i: Integer;
  AMyListOfRecords: TMyListOfRecords;
begin
  //other code

  //free AMyListOfRecords and all its content
  for i:=0 to AMyListOfRecords.Count-1 do
  begin
    AMyListOfRecords[i].SubList1.Free;
    AMyListOfRecords[i].SubList2.Free;
  end;
  AMyListOfRecords.Free;
end;
```

This seems to work. But I am wondering if there is a simpler or more elegant solution?

Comment: If you can use the DeHL then you can just use IList<> and that will be automatically managed as any other interfaced objects.

Comment: Otherwise you can just implement your own wrapper over IList<T> over TList<T> and do it TInterfacedObject.

Comment: Your code seems fine to me

Comment: I recommend using Spring4Ds interfaced generic collections - DeHL is just dead.

Comment: @StefanGlienke thanks for mentioning.. I just did not remember that as we are not yet using the Spring4D I was not able to rememeber where it was :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define the interfaced list for the sub-items like:

```
type
  TMyRecord=record
    Value1: Real;
    SubList1: IList<Integer>;
    SubList2: IList<Real>;
  end;

  TMyListOfRecords=TList<TMyRecord>;
```

Where IList is kind of:

```
type
  IList<T> = interface
    function Add(const AValue: T): Integer;
    function Remove(AValue: T): Integer;
  end;
```

where you implement it like this:

```
  TIntfList<T> = class(TInterfacedObject, IList<T>)
  private
    FList: TList<T>;
    function Add(const AValue: T): Integer;
    function Remove(AValue: T): Integer;

    constructor Create;
    destructor Destroy; override;
  end;

{ TIntfList<T> }

function TIntfList<T>.Add(const AValue: T): Integer;
begin
  Result := FList.Add(AValue);
end;

constructor TIntfList<T>.Create;
begin
  FList := TList<T>.Create;
end;

destructor TIntfList<T>.Destroy;
begin
  FList.Free;
  inherited;
end;

function TIntfList<T>.Remove(AValue: T): Integer;
begin
  Result := FList.Remove(AValue);
end;
```

After that you can assign fields of your record with TIntfList.Create and they will be released automatically with your records.

Answer (score 4):

You could transform record type to class - overhead is negligible because record already contains sub-objects. Free sub-objects in this class destructor, and use

```
 TMyListOfClasses = TObjectList<TMyClass>;
```

with `OwnsObjects = True`

In this case all you need is

```
AMyListOfClasses.Free;
```

Comment: Does it maintain a separate list of owned objects to destroy, or is it using RTTI for that?

Comment: @Michael TObjectList is just a list of objects, it destroys all its elements (if `OwnsObjects`), there is no need in separate list or RTTI

Comment: Yeah I am old school. I prefer to do the destructor because sometimes you dont have an owned option and I forget.